# dijit/form/select to select search fields in Arc JS API

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-js-api

I'm brand new to javascript, dojo and HTML and I've searched everywhere for examples of this and cannot find any.

I have a map with some feature points and a find task to highlight the feature points on the map, and display them in a grid with it's field attributes. This works great when I specify the search field as:

```
findParams.searchFields = ["LOCATION"];
```

But if I add:

```
findParams.searchFields = ["LOCATION", "MODEL_NUM"];
```

The grid displays results from multiple fields (ie. searching for attributes in LOCATION "A" would also find attributes in MODEL_NUM containing the letter "A"). So I decided to add a drop down menu select to specify which field to search in (one at a time) so the results are more precise.

So I added the following dijit:

```
<select id="fieldSelect" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" name="fieldSelect">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select a field</option>
          <option value="MODEL_NUM">Model Number</option>
          <option value="LOCATION">Location</option>
          <option value="NUM_DEFICIENCIES">Number of Deficiencies</option>
          <option value="INSTALL_DATE">Install Date</option>
</select>
```

I then modified the search field statement to:

```
findParams.searchFields = "[" + "\"" + dom.byId("fieldSelect").value +
"\"" + "]";
```

When I click my search button I get an Uncaught TypeError: a.join is not a function (FindParameters.js:5)

I hope this is enough information. Does anyone have a solution or a recommendation?

**UPDATE**

After a suggestion to pass an array and not a string to the findParams.searchFields, I made the following changes:

```
findParams.searchFields = [];  
findParmas.searchFields.push(dom.byId("fieldSelect").value);
```

This still gave me attribute results from multiple fields. After running a couple small tests:

```
var selectedField = document.getElementById('fieldSelect').value;
var index = selectedField.options[selectedField.selectedIndex].value;
```

And:

```
var selectedField = dom.byId('fieldSelect').value;
```

I'm finding that in the Chrome developer tools debugger, when I created a breakpoint at that line and executed the statement, both examples had the value of selectedField as 'undefined'.

Is this an issue of not getting the value from the drop down select dijit?

If no value is passed to findParams.searchFields, the API assumes all fields are valid, which is why I'm getting attribute results from multiple fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Ultimately it was the `registry.byId` that led me to the answer, I had to rearrange some code after I realized the `searchFields` was in the wrong function and not in the function that is called when I click the search button.

But when accessing the dijit, the only thing that worked was `registry.byId` to access the dijit node and pass the value of the selected value into my searchFields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dijit.byId` instead of `dom.byId`.

The following works for me:

```
var value = dijit.byId("fieldSelect").value;
if ("" != value) {
  findParams.searchFields = [value];
} else {
  findParams.searchFields = ["MODEL_NUM", "LOCATION", "NUM_DEFICIENCIES", "INSTALL_DATE"];
}
```